# Custom cursor and typeover text box

Tags: vb.net, textbox, cursor, overwrite

[image]

I need a text box and cursor so that I can type over existing image numbers as shown in this picture.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a `TextBox`.
2. Set Property `Multiline` to `True`
3. Set Font to `Consolas`
4. Set `WordWrap` to `False`
5. (optional) Set `ScrollBars` to `Both`

I'm not sure how to enable text overwrite when typing. Maybe someone else knows?

Answer (score 0):

Press the `Insert Key` on your keyboard. Use the `arrow keys` to navigate.

Done.

Unless you want to handle Keystroke events in your application, there is no other way.

Comment: Tried that...it did not typeover, it just inserted. :(